# Send a message from Server side to React front (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im currently trying to send a message from my server side and display it in my react front end.

I have tried everything to display the message I use with res.send() but the react fails to receive it can anyone help me point out what I am doing wrong here?

Sample of the front end:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';

export default class CreateFile extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeFileDescription = this.onChangeFileDescription.bind(this);



    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        file_description: '',

    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/api/isloggedin")
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.data) {
                return this.setState({isloggedin: false});
            }
        });

}



onChangeFileDescription(e) {
    this.setState({
        file_description: e.target.value
    });
}


onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(`Form submitted:`);
    console.log(`File Description: ${this.state.file_description}`);


    const newFile = {
        file_description: this.state.file_description,
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/files/add', newFile)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
        file_description: '',

    })
}

render() {
    return this.state.isloggedin ? (
        <div style={{marginTop: 20}}>

            <h3>Upload a New File</h3>


            <Tabs
                id="controlled-tab-example"
                activeKey={this.state.key}
                onSelect={key => this.setState({key})}
            >
                <Tab eventKey="audio" title="Audio">

                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>File Description: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   className="form-control"
                                   value={this.state.file_description}
                                   onChange={this.onChangeFileDescription}
                            />
                        </div>


            </Tabs>

        </div>
    ) : (
        <h3>Please login</h3>
    );
}
}
```

This is the server side:

Im checking if the submitted form is empty and if it is sending a error back asking users to fill the required field.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileRoutes = express.Router();
const File = require("../models/fileHandler");

module.exports = function(app) {


app.use(bodyParser.json());

fileRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    File.find(function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(files);
        }
    });
});

fileRoutes.route('/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    File.findById(id, function (err, file) {
        res.json(file);
    });
});


fileRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {

   console.log(req.body.file_description);

   if (req.body.file_description === ""){

       console.log("its empty!");
       var result = {"data" :"hello everybody !"}
       res.status(200).json({'description': 'description is needed'});
       return res.send(result);
   }


    let file = new File(req.body);
    file.save()
        .then(file => {
            res.status(200).json({'file': 'file added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new file failed');
        });
});


fileRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
    File.findById(req.params.id, function (err, file) {
        if (!file)
            res.status(404).send('data is not found');
        else
            file.file_description = req.body.file_description;
            file.file_size = req.body.file_size;
            file.file_duration = req.body.file_duration;
            file.file_artist = req.body.file_artist;
            file.file_bitrate = req.body.file_bitrate;
            file.file_codec = req.body.file_codec;
            file.file_audioChannels = req.body.file_audioChannels;
            file.file_dimensions = req.body.file_dimensions;
            file.file_tag = req.body.file_tag;
            file.file_colorProfile = req.body.file_colorProfile;
            file.file_extension = req.body.file_extension;
            file.file_employeeResponsible =         req.body.file_employeeResponsible;
            file.file_editActive = req.body.file_editActive;
            file.file_completed = req.body.file_completed;

        file.save().then(file => {
            res.json('File updated');
        })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});

app.use('/files', fileRoutes);

  };
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form to the server?

Comment: Yes i am I edited the question and added all of the code

Comment: `http://localhost:4000/` might be a different domain, and you don't have CORS enabled. Do you get an error in the Developer Tools console? What does it say about the request in the Network tab?

Comment: One thing that I want to mention is please move `axios.get()` from `constructor` to `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Thanks for the help I move the axios.get()

Comment: and Yes the console is receiving the message

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some digging I managed to solve this issue.
I thought i posted here in case anyone had a similar problem.

So what I did was to check everything with express validator and if there was any problem to send it to the react front end.

And in react front end if the there is any problem received regarding that specific field it will display it on top of the input field.
hope this helps.

```
  {this.state.errors &&
                        this.state.errors.file_description && <p>{this.state.errors.file_description.msg}
```

And the complete snippet of the react front end.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';

export default class CreateFile extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeFileDescription = this.onChangeFileDescription.bind(this);


    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        file_description: ''
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/api/isloggedin")
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.data) {
                return this.setState({isloggedin: false});
            }
        });

}



onChangeFileDescription(e) {
    this.setState({
        file_description: e.target.value
    });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(`Form submitted:`);
    console.log(`File Description: ${this.state.file_description}`);


    const newFile = {
        file_description: this.state.file_description

    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/files/add', newFile)
        .then(result => {
            if (result.data.errors) {
                return this.setState(result.data);
            }
            return this.setState({
                userdata: result.data,
                errors: null,
                success: true
            });
        });

    this.setState({
        file_description: ''

    })
}

render() {
    return this.state.isloggedin ? (
        <div style={{marginTop: 20}}>

            <h3>Upload a New File</h3>


                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>File Description: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   className="form-control"
                                   value={this.state.file_description}
                                   onChange={this.onChangeFileDescription}/>

                            {this.state.errors &&
                            this.state.errors.file_description && <p>{this.state.errors.file_description.msg}</p>}
                        </div>
                                <label className="form-check-label">Yes</label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </Tab>

            </Tabs>

        </div>
    ) : (
        <h3>Please login</h3>
    );
}
}
```

for the backend I have also tweaked it so if there is any problem it will post that back to the react front end validating with Express validator and using the normal route and post methods.

```
const express = require('express');
var { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileRoutes = express.Router();
const File = require("../models/fileHandler");

module.exports = function(app) {

const fileValidation = [
    check("file_description")
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
        .withMessage("Description required"),
];

app.use(bodyParser.json());

fileRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    File.find(function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(files);
        }
    });
});

fileRoutes.route('/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    File.findById(id, function (err, file) {
        res.json(file);
    });
});


fileRoutes.route('/add').post(fileValidation, function (req, res) {

    var errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.send({ errors: errors.mapped() });
    }else{

        console.log("its empty!");


        let file = new File(req.body);
        file.save()
            .then(file => {
                res.status(200).json({'file': 'file added successfully'});
            })
            .catch(err => res.send(err));
    }

});


fileRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
    File.findById(req.params.id, function (err, file) {
        if (!file)
            res.status(404).send('data is not found');
        else
            file.file_description = req.body.file_description;

        file.save().then(file => {
            res.json('File updated');
        })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});


app.use('/files', fileRoutes);

 };
```